# Why does xUnit tests are not visible in Test Explorer if dnx version is > to 451?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xunit

We made a whole new project, and we want to use xUnit as unit test. However, we want to target .net 4.6.0 and .net core 1.0.

We have all our project in net460 in all of our project.json. As far as I see, to be compatible with xUnit, we need to have our test project in dnx451. This is where we have a problem, because we target 460 at least ...

When we change to dnx460 in xUnit project.json, tests are not visible in test explorer ... ? Is there a reason ? Are we mistaking somewhere ?

We use VS2015.

Here's our project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "SESAMEngineFacturation.Tests Class Library",
  "authors": [ "christophe.mom" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "SESAMEngineFacturation": "",
    "xunit": "2.1.0",
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-*",
    "FluentAssertions": "4.2.2"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this GitHub issue : https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/600 I guess we have to wait for ASP.NET Core RC2 to be out in order to have dnx460 support for xunit.runner on VSTests and Resharper unit test explorer too.